# Ruby on Rails - Automated Email Sending - Flight Reminder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, cron, delayed-job

I'm creating flight booking website in Rails. Booking information is stored in database in the following table:

**USERNAME** | **FLIGHT FROM** | **FLIGHT TO** | **DATE OF FLIGHT** | **TIME OF FLIGHT** | **some additional information not relevant to this task ...** |

I'm looking to send an email an hour (or some specific time) before the **TIME OF FLIGHT** on a **DATE OF FLIGHT**. What is the best approach to do it ? I was looking into Cron and delayed_job however both seem to be based more on intervals rather than executing a job at specific date and time.

Please help.
Thank you

Comment: You may need to provide details of where you are hosting your Rails app for people to help you on this.

Comment: Thanks tommyd456,
It's going to be hosted on Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is just to have a cron job set to run every 10 minutes and determine via a database query which flights now require a reminder e-mail. You can have an additional field in the database such as "REMINDER_SENT" so that you only send an e-mail once.

If you are already using delayed job then the cron job should just call a ruby script which adds a SendReminders job on to the queue. You can then manage all of the db querying, e-mail sending and db updating from a normal delayed job.

This approach saves you having to queue up a large number of future dated events and you don't need to worry about flight times changing or events getting lost. If you miss one event then the next run in 10 minutes will pick up all the flights anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to send those notifications *exactly* one hour (or another time) in advance?

If not I would create a cron job that calls a rake task, say every 10 minutes. This task checks if there are notifications due and sends them. If you expect them to arrive 60 minutes before, with these settings you have a delivery timeframe between 60-70 minutes in advance, given the delays imposed by spam filters etc I think this is reasonable.

If you call the script more often (every minute), the precision is higher, but you might have trouble with concurrently running tasks.